# Using Intro.js hints on bootstrap modal window, hints displays behind modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the intro.js "hints" plugin (https://introjs.com/example/hint/index.html, https://introjs.com/docs/hints/api/) on a bootstrap web site. I need the hints to work on bootstrap modals, however the hints are displayed behind the modal window. I tried adjusting the z-index of the .introjs-hint-pulse and the .introjs-hint-dot selectors and the .modal selector with no results.

Any ideas on what I need to do to get the hints to display above the modal window as needed?

I also need to figure out how to hide all of the displayed hints at once, but then be able to show them again when the link is reclicked - like a toggle. I have one icon used to show the hints, and I want to be able to click again to toggle and hide the hints.

I am including links to the hints API, as it shows the options for refreshing and hiding the hints, but I am new to jQuery & JS and am not sure how to get it to work.

Also, I am trying to figure out a way to auto hide the hints on the modal if the modal is closed with them still visible.

I have a jsfiddle with a test modal and the intro.js hints. If you open the modal, then click on the "Show Hints" link, you will notice the hints are not visible. But if you close the modal you can see the hints are visible behind the modal window.
JS Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/998/

HTML of example:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a href="#notesModal" data-toggle="modal" role="dialog" id="btnOpenModal" class="btn btn-primary">Open Notes Modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="notesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="notesModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Notes</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="note-input" data-hint="Input your notes here." data-hintposition="top-middle" data-position="bottom-right-aligned">
               <input type="text" name="note" class="col-md-11" maxlength="300"/><button id="add-note" data-hint="Select Add button to save and add your notes." data-hintposition="top-middle" data-position="bottom-right-aligned">Add</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="note-total" data-hint="Track your remaining characters here." data-hintposition="top-middle" data-position="bottom-right-aligned" style="margin-left:15px;">0/300
      </div>          
      <div><a class="btn btn-tour" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:introJs().addHints();"><i class="fa fa-bus"></i>&nbsp;Show Hints</a></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The intro.js and introjs.css are linked in the jsfiddle external resources for viewing.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this CSS:

```
.introjs-hint {
    z-index: 9999999 !important;
}
```

In order to toggle hints you can (for example) do this:

```
var hints = false;

function toggleHints() {
    if (hints) {
    $("#txtToggle").html("&nbsp;Show Hints");
    introJs().hideHints();
  } else {
    $("#txtToggle").html("&nbsp;Hide Hints");
    introJs().showHints();
  }
    hints = !hints;
}
```

Check the fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/fc0rkakn/

Comment: That worked perfectly! I was applying the z-index to the wrong class (I was applying to the hint-pulse and hint-dot). Do you have any ideas how I can toggle the hints on and off with one button? The function to add the hints is: introJs.addHints() and to hide is: introJs.hideHints() - but I am not sure how to toggle them with one button. I also need to figure out how to refresh the hints when a new page is loaded, as it still shows any remaining hints from previous page. The api has a introJs.refresh() function that is supposed to refresh all hints, but not sure if this is what I need. Thanks!

Comment: For toggling hints on/off check my answer updated. On page load I think there is no need to refresh specifically the hints: they are loaded with the new page.

Comment: Beaver, you are awesome! Last question, I need to actually add the hints programmatically through options, like this:                  
 introJs.setOptions({
  hints: [
   {
    hint: 'Input your notes here',
    element: '#note-input',
        hintPosition: 'middle-left'
   },            
   {
    hint: 'Select Add button to save and add your notes.',
    element: '#add-note'
   },
   {
    hint: 'Track your remaining characters here',
    element: '#note-total'
   }
  ]
 }); How can I do this using your toggle code?

Comment: Beaver - here is an example of loading the hints programmatically: https://introjs.com/docs/hints/options/. I removed the hint attributes from the html elements and added them using the programmatic method, but it broke something, hints no longer work. I would also like to only have a font awesome icon (fa-question-circle) as the icon button, then when clicked to show hints, change to a close (fa-times-circle). I assume to do this, just need to change the .html to .class and add the fa class names in the (" "), right? Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/1007/

Comment: In general, if you found an answer good you should accept it. For other question please add them to SO

Comment: So I need to start a whole new question, and repeat everything we already discussed to see if someone can answer it? I can definitely do that, just seemed like it was much more efficient to ask as a follow up since your answer did help some with the toggle. Merry Christmas.